# change account linux uses for maintenance during boot failures

Tags: linux, debian, sudo, root, maintenance

If there is an issue during boot, then Linux will ask if you want to open a shell as `root` to repair. This is the message:

```
Give root password for maintenance
```

Is it possible to change this behavior to use a different ID instead? I have root logins disabled and use `sudo` through a different ID.

I'd like to have this error drop to the other ID and then use `sudo` to become root.